# Problema ao usar Select

Tags: select, materialize

Estou tentando usar o `form` `select` desse site aqui:
http://materializecss.com/forms.html

Porém quando coloco em meu site a única coisa que aparece é isso:

> "Materialize Multiple Select"

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

O código é esse:

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select multiple>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <label>Materialize Multiple Select</label>
  </div>
```

Comment: Você inicializou o plugin usando o: `$('select').not('.disabled').material_select();` ?

Comment: Sim, tambem nao funcionou =/

Comment: Você referenciou o arquivo jQuery.js antes do arquivo do materialize.js? Colocou eles no final da página antes do `</body>` ?

Comment: sim coloquei antes do /body

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode ser falta de algum arquivo. Adicione como você referenciou os mesmos em seu `html`.
Lembrando que você precisa "iniciar" o `material_select()`, desta forma:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select();
});
```

Um exemplo funcional do `select` está abaixo:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script><style type="text/css"></style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css">    
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select();
});
}//]]> 

</script>
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select multiple>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <label>Materialize Multiple Select</label>
  </div>
```

O mesmo pode ser visto no [JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/tnprzq1p/)

Relacionado: [Materialize CSS - Select Doesn't Seem to Render](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28258167/4843158)

Comment: Opa agora funcionou, eu apaguei as minhas referencias e usei a sua e funcionou, pode ser que meu arquivo estava com algum problema, vlw :D

Comment: @Ingi Essas são as próprias referências do site. Caso queira colocar local, você pode realizar o download das mesmas.

Comment: Então o meu estava local e não estava dando, será que o arquivo estava corrompido ?

Comment: @Ingi Se você baixou do site, dificilmente. É mais provável que esteja referenciando ele errado. Para ter certeza, basta abrir as opções de desenvolvedor (F12) e olhe se não está recebendo nenhum erro na aba console.