# <select> não aparece com Materialize

Tags: php, html, materialize

A tag select não aparece se eu importo o conteúdo da outra página, só se eu coloco direto na index. Segue o código:

index.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Cadastro de Carros!</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.css">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>


</head>
<body class="light-green lighten-5">

  <!-- NAVBAR -->

  <br />

  <div class="conteudo" id="conteudo">
    **<?php include 'controle.php' ?>**
  </div>

  <!--Revisar Footer -->
  <!--?php include 'footer.php' ?-->

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

controle.php

```html
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<div class="container white">
 
 <div class="row">
  <form class="col s12">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
     <input id="placa" type="text" class="validate">
     <label for="placa">Placa</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
     <input id="adesivo" type="number" class="validate">
     <label for="adesivo">Nº do adesivo</label>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
    <select>
     <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
     <option value="saab">Saab</option>
     <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
     <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <div class="input-field col s6">
     <input id="placa" type="text" class="validate">
     <label for="placa">Placa</label>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>


</div>
```

Comment: Não sei para que esses `***` mas falta um `;` no include....

Comment: foi um erro de digitação o ***, mas o include esta funcionando amigo, apenas o select não aparece, no entanto se eu inspeciono a página o código do select está la

Comment: Veja se [isto resolve o seu problema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/109076/20615)

Comment: Estava esquecendo de iniciar o material_select :S Valeu